# Não csg copiar um arquivo e renomeá-lo em seguida( OS, Shutil)

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um app onde preciso copiar uma imagem de dentro do pc do usuário e em seguida jogar a imagem numa pasta dentro de um diretório que se encontra o programa chamado de "/Imagens". Entretanto, mesmo sem ocorrer erros isso não acontece simplesmente nada acontece, já usei o "shutil.copy" e o "shutil.copy2" em ambos os dois nada ocorre, nem erro, nem a imagem e copiada e usando o "shutil.copyfile" Da o seguinte erro "Permission Denied", ou "Permissão negada". Alguém conhece uma forma de corrigir o erro, ou fazer isto funcionar ?

O programa em si tem quase 1000 linhas, mas a parte que eu acho que importa para esta problemática é da linha 929 à 980
(essa parte aki)

```
    def ImageSelect(self):
        self.master.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a Photo", filetypes=(("png files(RECOMENDADA)", "*.png"),("all files", "*.*")))
        self.top.focus()
        self.word = self.master.filename.split("/")
        self.caminho = self.master.filename.split(self.word[-1])
        print("----------------")
        print(self.word[-1])
        print(self.caminho[0])
        print("----------------")



    def Salvar_criado(self):

        Nome = self.entryN1.get()
        Telefone = self.entryT1.get()
        Endereco = self.entryE1.get()
        Funcao = self.entryR1.get()
        Idade = self.entryI1.get()

        if Nome in EQUIPI_DI:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Não foi possível realizar a ação desejada!",
                                        "Nome já existente no registro! Porfavor diferencie este contato do outro, ou, caso esteja querendo edita-lo, vá na opção editar.")
        else:
            if Nome == "" or Nome == " ":
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Nome Inválido")
            else:
                opcao = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("", "Você deseja salvar as alterações?", parent=self.top)
                if opcao > 0:
                    EQUIPI_DI[Nome] = {
                        'numero': Telefone,
                        'endereco': Endereco,
                        'funcao': Funcao,
                        "idade": Idade,
                    }

                    texto = open("[TEAM]" + Nome + ".txt", "x")
                    try:
                        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(self.caminho[0], self.word[-1]), os.path.join("/Images", self.word[-1]))
                        os.rename(f"/Images/{self.word[-1]}", f"/Images/{Nome}"+"[TEAM]"+".png")
                        print("______feito")
                    except Exception as error:
                        print(error)
                        pass

                    self.top.destroy()
                    self.master.destroy()
                    Window1.hospital_window(self.master)
                    salvar()
                else:
                    pass
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Nao tenho um conhecimento tao avançado de Python, mas se simplesmente não acontece nada como você diz, e vemos funções no seu codigo, vc já verifico se esta chamando as funções?

Comment: Então eu botei o print pensando nisso, e ele funciona, tanto é que caso eu bote em vez de shutil.copy, eu botar shutil.copyfile da um erro de permissão negada. Eu realmente não sei que pal ta dando kkk